# simple change of lists in python: efficient way?

Tags: python, list

if i have a list in python were i have a lot of numers example:

```
list = [1,2,3,12,4,5,23,5,6,56,8,57,8678,345,234,13, .....]
```

so a list of all integers, that all can have different values ... (i my case this list could be very long, and is actually not an integer list, but a list of Objects which are all from the same type an have a attribute age which is a integer)
whats the most efficient way to add all those values by +1
is it

```
new_list = [x+1 for x in list]
```

or maybe

```
new_list = []
for x in list:
    new_list.append(x+1)
```

(i guess it makes no difference)

or is there maby a more efficent way or an other data sructure to make this more performant?
I really wonder if there is not any method, maybe using something different the a list were i can do this operation more efficient because the +1 seems son simple ...

Comment: You can try both and time them ;)

Comment: Are they all getting one year older? You might consider storing a birth date instead and make age a property that calculates itself based on the current date.

Comment: @schwobaseggl yes in the mainloop of my programm all are getting one "year" older. You have a interesting idea which would work in some cases, but in mine i have to check in every step of the loop if one of them passed a maxAge and then delete it from the list. So is think to calculate the age every time is not as good ass adding one to everyone ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you actually have a list of objects with an integer attribute, as you say, you can update the attribute in-place:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

my_list = [A(2), A(5), A(1)]
for obj in my_list:
    obj.x += 1
assert my_list[0].x == 3
assert my_list[1].x == 6
assert my_list[2].x == 2
```

Comment: thanks but thats what i'm actually doing. I just wanted to simplyfiy the problem. I cant see in which way your approach should be any faster... Or am i missed there something?

Comment: That's as simple as it gets. It should be a little faster, as you aren't having to create any new objects or lists; you are simply modifying existing objects.

Answer (score 0):

There is no fastest way but I think this is an interesting attempt since u never use more RAM than actually needed (u delete the entries once you copied them)

```
list1 = []
while (len(list) != 0):
    list1.append(list.pop(0)+1)
```

After receiving a comment I did some testing and found the results very interesting!

[image: Testing results.]

Comment: This would work, but as the docs mention, `list.pop(0)` is not very efficient, because all the following items in the list have to be moved down. And since you're looping over every list item, you've turned a O(n) problem into a O(n²) problem.

Comment: very interesting that the second one is so more effective than the first one. I would have thought that they do exactly the same ...

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `map`. It must be fast due to some built-in optimizations.

```
t = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
print (map(lambda x:x + 1, t))
```

Comment: Not so sure `map` is best in connection with `lambda`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map

Comment: That won't work in Python 3, since `map` returns an iterator, not a list. So in Python 3 you can either wrap the `map` call in `list()`, or unpack the iterator with the `*` splat operator: `print(*map(lambda x:x + 1, t))`. But in both Python 2 & 3 you can make it more efficient by getting rid of that lambda, and directly calling the `__add__` method of the 1 integer object:  `print(list(map((1).__add__, t)))`